# PHPunit: Problems with testing

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, testing, phpunit

I have run into a major problem while writing tests. I am using Laravel 5.6.0 as framework and PHPUnit 7.0 for testing. As a testing DB I have used sqlite with storage in memory. This is from my `database.php`:

```
'sqlite_testing' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

But my problem is that I have several places where I use `whereRaw`, for example `$query->whereRaw('STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`date`, " ",`from`), "%Y-%m-%d %k") < ?', [$before]);`. The problem here is that sqlite does not have the `STR_TO_DATE` or `CONCAT` functions that MySQL has. So PHPUnut throws a bunch of errors because of that.

My solution was instead using a MySQL DB as testing DB. But this doesn't seem to work since I get several different errors, mostly I have several tests where foreign key constraint fails.

One exaple for this is that I have the following in my Base TestCase `setUp` method:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('gym_schedule') && !empty(GymSchedule::createGymSchedules())) {
    $this->artisan('db:seed', ['--class' => 'GymScheduleTableSeeder']);
}
```

This fails every time except the first because it says that `a schedùle with id 1` already exists (`id` is my primary key). I did try to truncate all tables between each test class using `tearDown`, but that did not help at all, and also the testing became reeeeally slow, like 3 seconds for each test.

So basically that approach does not work either.

I am at a loss. I have tried googling this and searching through StackOverflow. I am open to any suggestion that is not too complicated (either remove all MySQL functions somehow, solve usage of MySQL or anything else really).

Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Did you try [resetting the database](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) with the `RefreshDatabase` trait ?

Comment: @RamyHerrira yes I saw now that the previous developer on this project used that in every test, so that is not working.

Comment: How so ? Could you be more specific ? Is it displaying an error ?

Comment: @RamyHerrira Each Test Class already has `use RefreshDatabase;` but when I run several of the tests I get for example `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gym_testing`.`workout`, CONSTRAINT `workout_workout_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`workout_type_id`) REFERENCES `workout_type` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `workout` (`date`, `from`, `personal_trainer_id`, `workout_type_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-11-19, 16, , 1, 2018-11-19 16:52:07, 2018-11-19 16:52:07))`

Comment: I would argue that testing your application in a way that isn't realistic is kind of redundant

Comment: Honestly I don't know if there is anyone who can successfully test a complex laravel application with sqlite queries. Facing the same problems right now with sqlite. `No such function CONCAT`

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the first part of the question, unit testing a Laravel app when using `whereRaw()`, this is how I wrote the methods:

```
    $raw_condition = "CONCAT(`country_code`, `number`) = ?"; 

    if (env('DB_CONNECTION') === 'sqlite') {
        $raw_condition = "(`country_code` || `number`) = ?";
    }

    return Model::whereRaw($raw_condition, [$number])->firstOrFail();
```